# What is a good PHP Editor for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am c# developer working on a Word Press site.  I am used to the Visual Studio experience of opening the project, working on it, then pressing run to see your site and debug it.

I am having a hard time trying to get a similar experience with WordPress.  For example, I have tried both VS plugs for PHP.  They both work great for new PHP projects, but with a fresh copy of the latest wordpress, the both break.  In one, it just gives an error message, the other says that the MySQL Plugin is not enabled. (Yes, MySQL is installed and I can successfully host WordPress with MySQL through IIS).   Dispite messages on both forums, I have not been able to resolve.

So the question is: what is a good editor, free or paid for working with wordpress sites? Just something that works. Like have you actually used one successfully with WordPress?  My latest attempt is with PHP Storm which looks really good, but am still struggling with the learning curve of a new IDE.  I would really like to be able to stay with VS if possible, as I like the Source Control.

Comment: [`PHPStorm`](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) without a doubt :X (Despite you've tried, there an't much better!)

Comment: PHPStorm is what I use. I've used Eclipse and VS for PHP. Storm is the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPStorm is the best one and you can try it for free for 30 days.

Elcipse and Netbeans are both really good as well and free.

Answer (score 0):

So here is my top3 editors that i'm working with:
Sublime text 3 - http://www.sublimetext.com/3
Apstana Studio - http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3
Brackets - http://brackets.io/

Comment: +1 for Sublime text. It's so great!!!

Answer (score 0):

Komodo IDE is in my opinion the most complete and fast and best PHP editor. In fact it's not only an editor but  Active State also has a free version of Komodo Edit. It uses the Mozilla xul render engine: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveState_Komodo

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/)?

I have been using it for 3 years now and it's great. It has built in support for Zend framework, Symphony, Hudson/Jenkins, Doctrine 2, PHPUnit, Atoum, APIGen and many more.

Some of its features include:

- PHP Source Code Editor offering code templates and code generation, refactoring, parameter tooltips, hints and quick fixes, and smart code completion.
- PHP 5.4 Support
- Continuous Integration Support
- PHP Debugging
- Remote and Local Project Development
- Code Coverage
- Namespace and Variable Types
- MySQL Integration
- Documenting PHP Code with ApiGen

Comment: I dumped NetBeans for Sublime Text, mostly due to how slow Netbeans can get. This becomes more apparent the larger the projects become and the longer you keep the IDE open. Sublime Text is not so much an IDE and much more of a text editor. But the speed is phenomenal.

Comment: @francisco.preller well I agree that Netbeans used to be slow, but I have to say that the newer versions improved performance a lot. It won't beat a text editor of course, but the frameworks and features provided by Netbeans IMHO outweigh the drawbacks. Still I agree that it should be faster.

Comment: If I were to pick an IDE over a text editor I'd put my money on PHPStorm from Jetbrains, but granted, the price tag on Netbeans is quite attractive too.